# Getting an Access Token for back-end server use

Tags: microsoft-graph-api, onedrive

I need to get an access token for my server to user without a user having to authenticate.

I do this for DropBox and want to do it for OneDrive.

I have a service that needs to save files in its own OneDrive acct and then also copy some files to users' accts.

For the user we will authenticate with either the Token or Code flow. However, for the server I just want to have access token. In DropBox you get the access token on the App Settings page, but I can't figure out how to do it for Graph

Comment: Some code samples to explain what you are trying would be nice.

Answer (score 1):

Assuming you're talking about OneDrive Business, it sounds like you want to get an [app-only token](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/graph/auth-v2-service?context=graph%2Fapi%2F1.0&view=graph-rest-1.0). Such a token will require a tenant administrator to consent, but after that it can access the service without any user.

If you're talking about OneDrive Personal the scenario isn't possible - all tokens are required to have app and user claims, and therefore require to sign in.

Comment: This sounds like what I am looking for. I will check it out. Knowing the right words makes all the difference.  Thanks.